# how to put characters combination as constant command into iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, frameworks, ascii

I am new to iOS programming. I am developing some SDK framework right now. I have a command with three characters: 'ESC' 'E' '1', I wanna combine those three characters to generate a NSString and put this NSString into framework. Therefore others can directly use this Constant in framework.

Any one knows how to do this? Because in the constant.h file, you cannot use any run-time functions such as StringWithFormat.

I also think about using \u to combine three characters. doing like this way: NSString *message2 = @"\\u001b\\u002d\\u0031"; but it failed. This is considered as this long String: \\u001b\\u002d\\u0031 rather than ESC+E+1

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u` universal characters are restricted by ISO 10646 to exclude certain characters. Of particular interest to you is ESC. But you can encode this in octal:

```
NSString *message2 = @"\033E1";
```

Note that you typically do not put these in the header file. You typically implement this this way:

#### MYMessages.h

```
// Declare it here
extern NSString * const MYMessage2;
```

#### MYMessages.m

```
// Define it here
NSString * const MYMessage2 = @"...";
```

As much as possible, avoid generic files like `constant.h`. Place your constants in the header that most closely matches. For example, `NSGlobalDomain` is a string constant defined in `NSUserDefaults.h` because it's used with user defaults. There's no global "CocoaStringConstants.h" file.